# How to create scrollable and editable datatable in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I need to create scrollable and editable datatable. What I found is changing style class to "ui-editable-column" but it didnt work for me. Is there any other way to create a datatable like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PrimeFaces Showcase you can find examples for (amongst loads of other examples):

- [Row Editing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf)
- [Scrolling](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableScrolling.jsf)
- [Cell Editing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf)